# How to colorize QGIS hillshades without including black tones?

Tags: qgis, hillshade

**Background:**

In a [recent video](https://adventuresinmapping.com/2023/03/02/throwing-shade-in-wild-color/), John Nelson showed how to make multi-hued hillshades in ArcGIS Pro.  I am trying to re-create his efforts using QGIS 3.22.16.

At 1:55 he changes the hillshade color gradient from black-to-white to green-to-white.
Here's a screenshot depicting his settings:

[image]

And here's the resulting image (*Important*: note that the directly-illuminated slopes are white, while the most-shadowed slopes are the darkest green):

[image]

Using my own DEM data in 3.22.16, the only hillshade colorizing option that I've found is the "colorize" button.  Here are my settings:

[image]

In the resulting hillshade, the directly-illuminated slopes are white (as expected), but the most-shadowed slopes are ***instead shaded black***:

[image]

**Queston:**

How to colorize DEM hillshades in QGIS so that the most-shadowed areas are not black, but instead are the darkest selected color?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't directly use the DEM + style options to generate hillshade + custom colour ramp as try to you do.

You need to generate a hillshade raster (use `raster tools >hillshade` or the `processing toolbox`)

And **then only** use a custom colour ramp on this native  hillshade layer (color/transparency vs hillshade value).

With that approach, JMNelson's tutorials work perfectly in QGIS.

By the way, he actually does the same in Arcgis: generate some 'native' hillshade layers & then style them.